# Plot each value in a time series dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I have a CSV file that shows the price of a product's barcode for several supermarkets during the COVID pandemic.
The `dataframe.head()` looks like this:

```
             BARCODE          AC    BFRESH  LIDL    SUPERM  
Date                            
2020-01-03  5201263086618   6.36    7.97    0   0   8.31             
2020-01-03  5201263086625   7.58    9.53    0   0   9.91    
2020-01-03  7322540574852   18.11   18.34   0   0   8.86    
2020-01-03  7322540647136   18.8    18.95   0   0   18.9    
2020-01-03  7322540587555   18.22   18.98   0   0   9.21
```

In the dataset, there are 968 unique barcodes and the dataset also has 42592 entries, which means that some barcodes are present more than once in the dataset, so there are fluctuations in the product's prices.

I want to plot them somehow so that in one plot (preferably a line plot) all of the products are present clearly showing the ups and downs of the prices in different supermarkets (if any). Do you think there's a way to do that? I haven't found anything that matches my requirements just yet.

---

Following a few comments around my decision on plotting 968 barcodes, I agree that it can be messy. It is just my first attempt/ approach to "look" at the data and maybe analyze the different prices on a few products and how they fluctuated during the COVID pandemic. I am open to suggestions on how to approach this.

Comment: I think the motive behind the downvote is the fact, that you want to display. 968 different product. In the same plot, there is no natural reason to try to achieve that.  Unless you want instead to see the average variation of the prices in the conjunction of product.

Answer (score 1):

It is technically possible, but are you sure that's what you want?

You're asking for (968 unique barcodes * 4 shopping centers) 3872 individual lines on a single plot. It would be impossible to interpret. What is the question you're trying to answer? There are a few better ways to generate a meaningful plot, e.g. try plotting

- average price of all products per supermarket over time. That gives you 4 lines. This gives an idea of how prices are trending, or which stores changed products/prices during the pandemic

`dataframe.groupby(["Date"])['AC','BFRESH','LIDL','SUPERM'].mean().plot()`

[image: Plot showing supermarket trends over all products (Extended the dataset randomly by 2 days)]

Or you could look for the most common product, filter for only it, and plot its price over time (here mean is selected because of how groupbys work, but there's only one barcode in the dataframe, so you could do .max(), .mix(), etc with the same result).

```
df = dataframe
df = df[df.BARCODE == df.BARCODE.value_counts().idxmax()]
df.groupby(["Date"])['AC','BFRESH','LIDL','SUPERM'].mean().plot()
```

[image: Plot showing supermarket trends for the most common product (Extended the dataset randomly by 2 days)]

*Artificially extended dataset in csv format below*

```
    Date,BARCODE,AC,BFRESH,LIDL,SUPERM
2020-01-03,5201263086618, 2.36,2.97,0, 8.31
2020-01-03,5201263086625, 3.58,9.53,0, 9.91
2020-01-03,7322540574852, 12.11,10.34, 0, 8.86
2020-01-03,7322540647136, 18.8,18.95, 0, 18.9
2020-01-03,7322540587555, 18.22,18.98, 0, 9.21
2020-01-05,5201263086618, 6.36,7.97,0, 3.31
2020-01-05,5201263086625, 7.58,9.53,0, 9.91
2020-01-05,7322540574852, 18.11,18.34, 0, 4.86
2020-01-05,7322540647136, 18.8,18.95, 0, 15.9
2020-01-05,7322540587555, 18.22,18.98, 0, 9.21
2020-01-08,5201263086618, 2.36,7.97,0, 3.31
2020-01-08,5201263086625, 2.58,9.53,0, 9.91
2020-01-08,7322540574852, 18.11,18.34, 0, 4.86
2020-01-08,7322540647136, 12.8,18.95, 0, 15.9
```